# Text processing in bash: Add header as column in every row

Tags: unix

please help here to modify the output as below.

Input:

```
192.9.23.58
AU4SNK I11
AU4SNK I2
AU4SNK I2
192.9.24.78
AU4SNK I11
AU4SNK I2
```

Output:

```
192.9.23.58 AU4SNK I11
192.9.23.58 AU4SNK I2 
192.9.23.58 AU4SNK I2 
192.9.24.78 AU4SNK I11 
192.9.24.78 AU4SNK I2
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ6vL.png)

Comment: Actually its not tr...I removed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution in bash.

```
bash >O<I -c 'while read l;do [[ $l =~ ^([0-9]+\.){3} ]]&&x=$l||echo $x $l;done'
```

Replace `I` and `O` with the names of your input file and your output file.